# Why is the change from HTTP to HTTPS in View Settings within Google Analytics important?

Tags: google-analytics

I have an HTTPS site which runs on SSL since years, also the Google Search Console is configured with HTTPS. If you lookup a page of that site through HTTP, a redirect to HTTPS will take place.

Now I found out, that within `Google Analytics > View Settings`, the property `Website's URL` ist still configured with HTTP (in that dropdown menu there). But in `Google Analytics > Property Settings`, it's correctly configured with HTTPS.

As I don't want to create a negative impact on any data collected within the last 10 years, would the property change have an impact on the data? Why is it important that this property is actually on the currently used protocol? Because data is collected, everything is actually there, so why should I need to change it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That setting has no impact on data. It doesn't change automatically, you have to be the one to set it. It is used, for example, to preview the page by clicking on the icon in the page report.

Comment: Thanks, so if it has no impact on how data is reported (e.g. Referral etc.), I will correct it.